# Installing Radiant Stiff Board Insulation

Tags: insulation, installation

I'm in the process of renovating a bedroom on the second floor and I have a few boards of silverboard (a Polyisocyanurate Foam Board Insulation) lying around and would like to use. The exterior wall is brick followed by a spacing followed by another wall (some sort of concrete). Since the silverboard has radiant shielding on both sides and sandwiches a stiff foam board, would I:

1) install the silverboard in contact with concrete wall, or

2) leave a spacing in between the concrete wall and the silverboard?

Comment: Are you installing the insulation on the inside or the outside of the concrete wall?

Comment: The insulation will be on the inside, it's my first time using such a product. If it was regular radiant shielding then I would leave a gap, but because this has a foam board it complicates matters.

Comment: Does the wall already have a vapor/air barrier in the assembly, or is it a pure mass wall with no insulation or barrier layers?  Or is it ICF?

Comment: To @ThreePhaseEel's point, do you already have insulation on ... I mean, IN the wall? I would not use foamboard at all inside of the wall. Instead, I would use a roll foam or heck, the messy "new" spray foam. but not a foam board. it will not serve its purpos inbetween joists, and you do not want it compressing under a drywall either.

Comment: No vapor barrier, no insulation, its just a brick wall on the outside and a slab on the inside. There is an air gap in between the brick wall and the slab, also no ICF.

Comment: @noybman there is zero insulation

Comment: @noybman can you install the board in between the studs followed by fiberglass insulation?

Comment: While you CAN.... you really shouldn't. The idea with that board is UV/heat reflective as well as prevents air from coming in through cracks, lastly, is a space barrier. In a wall cavity, it wouldn't perform any of these jobs (very well). Rolled, cellulose, etc, can fill teh gaps and fill them more tightly that rigid foam board.

Comment: Are there studs or furring strips on the inside of the wall to begin with?

Comment: @noybman -- it is quite possible that there are no studs to be had in this assembly (it looks to be a back ventilated (yay) brick veneer cladding over a concrete mass wall)

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel very very true.... but... he is remodeling.... so..... there should be studs now! :)

Comment: @noybman -- not necessarily -- I wouldn't put studs in if I was in his shoes.  Instead, I'd put down continuous foamboard and then lag furring strips to the concrete through the foam, using the foamboard's shear strength to prevent bending of the fasteners.

Comment: If that was the case, and you were interested in insulation, what would you do (besides vapor barrier)? would you still put in a sheet of foam board? It wouldn't provide much insulation R value

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65622/discussion-between-noybman-and-threephaseeel).

Comment: @noybman -- you can put 4-6" (or perhaps more) of foamboard in in that config

Comment: @nonameswereavailable -- how thick is your foamboard, and how many layers of foamboard do you have the foamboard for?

Comment: @nonameswereavailable -- also, is there a reason you want to insulate this one room, instead of gathering up your foamboard supplies and insulating on the exterior of the structural wall?

Comment: The boards are about a 1/2 inch thick. I have enough foam board the cover this one room plus a little more for another room. It's been in storage for a few months now and I would like to take advantage of it (if possible). I'm insulating this one room as a test case to see how effective I can make it. It needs to insulated regardless since I reside in a northern climate, where it drops below 0 in the winter. I'm under the impression that insulatting on the exterior would require more work since I believe I would have to remove the brick wall.